# ASP.Net Core 6.0 OnGet handler not called when an anchor link is clicked

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have the following html piece of code, which holds several links (This is one part of the Layout, which is used in my Razor pages):

```html
<div class="footer-left">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/CookieList">Cookies List</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Terms">Terms of use</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I have an OnGet handler for the About page:

```cs
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
  private readonly DbDuhnjaContext mDataContext;

  public AboutModel(DbDuhnjaContext aDataContext)
  {
     mDataContext = aDataContext;
  }

  public void OnGet()
  {
     // Some code
  }
}
```

When I open the page by typing its path in the browser: https://mywebsite.com/About or refresh the page, it calls the OnGet method correctly. But if I click on the  link it does not calls the method.

What am I missing here?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new empty Razor Page, it creates the PageModel (cshtml.cs) and the Razor View (cshtml).

Your PageModel appears to be fine, but what is missing from the Razor View is what you'll see at the top of a new empty Razor Page.  The `@page` directive (with no route in this case) and a `@model` attribute, which allows you to access the code behind in a strongly typed manner from the view.

Lastly, and most likely the cause of your links not using the AspNetCore routing, you should be using the `asp-page` [Anchor TagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in your anchor tags.

```
@page
@model MyProjectName.Pages.AboutModel
<div class="footer-left">
    <ul>
        <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a asp-page="/CookieList">Cookies List</a></li>
        <li><a asp-page="/Terms">Terms of use</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you are not working from a File->New AspNetCore Web App you may also need to register the tag helpers in your `Shared\_ViewImports.cshtml`

```
// ...
@addTagHelper *,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't been explicit. So the code I shared is just a part of the Layout used in all my pages. There is more code to it. I updated my question. And yes, my pages have the page and model directives. I tried to change the href tag to asp-page but the result is still the same. And I have the addTagHelper in my _ViewImports.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry, it seems that the problem was on my side. The About page was served from the cache when I click on the link, and that cache contained a version where the OnGet handler was not implemented yet. After I cleared the cache it started working. Thank you